# Solve $\int_0^{\infty} x^2 \frac{x}{\theta}e^{\frac{x^2}{2\theta}} dx $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, substitution

**Solve** $$\int_0^{\infty} x^2 \frac{x}{\theta}e^{\frac{x^2}{2\theta}} dx $$

**Solution:**
$$\int_0^{\infty} x^2 \frac{x}{\theta}e^{\frac{x^2}{2\theta}} dx = - \int_0^\infty x^2 de^{\frac{-x^2}{2\theta}}dx^2 $$

By partial integration:

$$= \int_0^\infty e \frac{-x^2}{2\theta}dx^2$$

And taking substitution $u=\frac{x^2}{2\theta}$:

$$ = 2\theta \int_0^\infty e^{-u} du = 2\theta$$

**Questions**

I do not understand the solution provided, threfore I ask for a detailed breakdown which explains issues such as:

1. In $- \int_0^\infty x^2 de^{\frac{-x^2}{2\theta}}dx^2$ - what is the meaning of $de$?
2. Does $dx^2$ Mean that the whole expression is to be integrated twice?

Comment: The integral for $\theta>0$ diverges

Comment: This equation is wrong (actually, it makes no sense) $$\int_0^{\infty} x^2 \frac{x}{\theta}e^{\frac{x^2}{2\theta}} dx = - \int_0^\infty x^2 de^{\frac{-x^2}{2\theta}}dx^2$$

Comment: @YuriyS OK, maybe you can explain why?

Comment: @ user1607, the integral diverges because for $x \to \infty$ the function $e^{x^2}$ grows out of bounds, and this makes the integral diverge. Unless $\theta <0$, then $e^{-x^2/| \theta|}$ falls to $0$ for $x \to \infty$

Comment: As for the second comment, what $de^{\frac{-x^2}{2\theta}}dx^2$ is supposed to mean?

Comment: @YuriyS for the meaning of the expression, that was also my question (see Question 1 in my post) i thought it was some comon notation which i didnt know about, but apparently it is not...

Comment: What is the source of this "solution"

Comment: $dx^2$ usually means $d(x^2)$ in other words, changing the variable so  $y=x^2$. In the same way $de^{-x^2/(2 \theta)}$ should mean $d(e^{-x^2/(2 \theta)})$ or changing the variable so $y=e^{-x^2/(2 \theta)}$. You can't have both at the same time

Comment: Did you miss a minus sign in $\mathrm e^{x^2/2\theta}$? The integral you gave clearly does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers:

1. I think that actually means
   $$
   \newcommand\diff{\,\mathrm d}
   \newcommand\e{\mathrm e}
   \diff \left( \e^{-x^2/2\theta} \right), 
   $$
   while
   $$
   \diff \e^{-x^2/2 \theta}
   $$
   does not make much sense;
2. $\diff x^2$ is a short hand for $(\diff x)^2$, while the differential of $x^2$ should be $\diff (x^2)$. I think the "solution" means the latter.

Additionally, the integral you gave does not converge, so I assume that you are actually requested to compute
$$
\int_0^{+\infty} x^2 \cdot \frac x \theta \e^{-x^2/(2\theta)} \diff x,
$$
for $\theta>0$ 
which we could compute as the following:
$$
\int_0^{+\infty} x^2 \cdot \frac x \theta \e^{-x^2/(2\theta)} \diff x = \int_0^{+\infty} x^2 \e^{-x^2/(2\theta)} \diff \left(\frac {x^2}{2\theta}\right) = -\int_0^{+\infty} x^2 \diff (\e^{-x^2/(2\theta)}) = \left. x^2\e^{-x^2/(2\theta)}\right\vert_{+\infty}^0 + \int_0^{+\infty} \e^{-x^2/(2\theta)} \diff (x^2) = \cdots
$$
and the rest is left to you.

P.S. This is actually a question of "improper integrals", so maybe the tag could be changed to this kind.

Comment: i am trying to understand you solution, however i still have some issues. Does the notation $d(e^{\frac{-x^2}{2\theta}})$ mean that substitution is used? I basically cannot understand this part: $$\int_0^{\infty} x^2 e^{\frac{-x^2}{2\theta}}  d(\frac{x^2}{2\theta}) = - \int_0^\infty x^2   d(e^{\frac{-x^2}{2\theta}} )$$ could you break this down?

Comment: @user1607 You could let $u = x^2/2\theta$, then the integral is $$  \int_0^{+\infty} 2\theta u \mathrm e^{u} \mathrm d(-u) = -\int_0^{+\infty} 2\theta u \mathrm d(\mathrm e^{u}) =- \int_0^{+\infty} x^2 \mathrm d(\mathrm e^{x^2/(2\theta)}),$$ where we used $d(\mathrm e^u) = \mathrm e^u \mathrm d u$ and we substitute $x$  back for $u$.

Comment: but if $u=\frac{x^2}{2\theta}$, is there a missing minus sign in the exponent? Such that: $$ \int_0^\infty 2\theta ue^{-u}du = -2\theta \int_0^\infty ue^udu$$ Then applying integration by parts where $q=u, q' = 1, v'=e^u, v=e^u$ I get $$ -2\theta[qe^u-\int e^udu]=-2\theta(e^uq-e^u)$$ and substituting back i have: $$ -2\theta [e^{\frac{-x^2}{2\theta}}(-\frac{x^2}{2\theta})-e^{\frac{-x^2}{2\theta}}]_0^\infty$$ Then taking limits $e^\infty -> 0 \text{ and } e^0->1$: $$ -2\theta[-\frac{1}{2\theta}-1]=2\theta +1$$ Where am i doing a mistake? The result should be $2\theta$...

Comment: My bad, i copied wrong. If $u = x^2/(2\theta)$, then $$  \int_0^{+\infty} 2\theta u \mathrm e^{-u} \mathrm du = - \int_0^{+\infty} 2\theta u \mathrm e^{-u} \mathrm  d(-u) = -\int_0^{+\infty} 2\theta u  \mathrm d(\mathrm e^{-u})$$ where you could additionally let $v =-u$ and use $\mathrm d(\mathrm e^v) = \mathrm e^v \mathrm dv$.

Answer (score 0):

1) This doesn't make much sense, you can obtain the result using:

$\int \frac{x^2 x \left(\exp  x^2\right)}{(2 \theta ) \theta } \, dx=\text{constant}+e^{\frac{x^2}{2 \theta }} \left(x^2-2 \theta \right)$

For this, you will use the same substitution $u = \frac{x^2}{2 \theta}$ and integrate it by parts.

Then you evaluate it using the fundamental theorem of calculus. The infinity limit is evaluated taking the limit of $x\rightarrow \infty$.

$ \int_0^{\infty } \frac{x^2 x \left(\exp  x^2\right)}{(2 \theta ) \theta } \, dx=2 \theta $

Which is only true if  $\text{Re}(\theta)<0$. Otherwise the integral diverges.

2) Means that the integral is respectively to $x^2$. Just like:

$\int \sin(x)d\sin(x)=\frac{\sin^2(x)}{2}+C$

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Math.SE. This is not an answer. Once you have enough reputation you can post comments. Of course, in this case, your link is useful, as not everyone has WA pro, but I would suggest you type the important parts of the solution in the body of this post instead of just linking a picture

Comment: Oh, I see. I will keep that in mind next time.

Comment: You can still edit this answer to include the relevant information. This way it is more likely to be upvoted. Just an advice though